# Basic Sprite/UIImage Movement in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'd like to move an image from one side of the screen to another.

I have two UIImageViews, ball1 and ball2. One on the left and one on the right respectively. The device is in landscape mode.
When the user clicks a button, I want them to switch sides, like a motion tween. Ive tried using CGPoint but i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two CGPoints and an NSTimer in your header,

```
CGPoint pos1;
CGPoint pos2;
NSTimer *timer;
```

In any other method prior to moving the images, set your CGPoints which will be used as the speed of your images. Since you are moving horizontally, the CGPoint asks for x and y parameters respectively. In this example, use `(2.0,0.0);` and `(-2.0,0.0);` for right and left respectively.

```
pos = CGPointMake(2.0,0.0);    
pos2 = CGPointMake(-2.0,0.0);
```

And then Set the timer to fire off a method called "move"

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector (move) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Create another timer that is not globally declared to stop the balls from moving using a method called `stopBalls`. (Assuming it takes two seconds to do this. Experiment and replace the `2.0` with whatever works)

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector (stopBall) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Create the `-(void)move` method which uses CGPoints and the `pos` variables to move the images. Assuming the images are named `ball1` and `ball2`.

```
-(void)move
{
    ball1.center = CGPointMake(ball1.center.x+pos1.x,ball1.center.y +pos1.y);
    if (ball1.center.x > 2024 || ball1.center.x < 0)
        pos1.x = -pos1.x;
    if (ball1.center.y > 768 || ball1.center.y < 0)
        pos1.y = -pos1.y;

    ball2.center = CGPointMake(ball2.center.x+pos2.x,ball2.center.y +pos2.y);
    if (ball2.center.x > 2024 || ball2.center.x < 0)
        pos2.x = -pos2.x;
    if (ball2.center.y > 768 || ball2.center.y < 0)
        pos2.y = -pos2.y;
}
```

And then create the `stopBalls` method to stop the balls from moving. This resets the CGPoint and stops `timer`.

```
-(void)stopBalls
{
    pos = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);    
    pos2 = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0); 
    [timer invalidate];
}
```

Simply rerun the method used to initiate the movement to do it again.

Also do NOT run the method more than once while the balls are moving, as this doubles the speed as another timer with `(2.0,0.0);` and `(-2.0,0.0);` is fired off.

Comment: a little more than what i was looking for but it gives me a snippet to edit and play around with. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
CGPoint firstCenter = ball1.center;
CGPoint secondCenter = ball2.center;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    ball1.center = secondCenter;
    ball2.center = firstCenter;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

well For Sprite Movement Try this [LINK](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3alesson_2._your_first_game)

Regarding your Question, You can use Core Animation and change the Position of the Balls
that should do i guess